# how to use trailing context in readable patterns with Flex?

Tags: flex-lexer

In Flex, I can use the a trailing pattern in a name definition like this:

```
NAME  foo$|bar
```

and this passes flex.

But I don't like to write regular expressions like this, without whitespace, as they are hard to read.  So I would like to do properly:

```
NAME  (?x: foo$ | bar )
```

but now this fails flex because, according to the manual, `"‘$’, cannot be grouped inside parentheses"`.

IMHO, this is silly, to allow some construct, but to not allow to describe it readably.

How can I use trailing context with a readable pattern in Flex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to answer your question: "How can I use trailing context with a readable pattern in Flex?". If you insist that patterns are only readable if they are sprinkled with whitespace, then the answer is ***"You cannot."*** Sorry, but that's the way it is. The `(?x:` flag was hacked into flex at some point, and there are still a lot of rough edges.

In a way, it doesn't matter since you cannot use the <kbd>$</kbd> operator as part of one alternative in an `r|s` regular expression. So even if you could have used the "readable syntax", it wouldn't have meant what you intended. You can certainly use the following "readable syntax" (at least, I think it's readable). It means something different, but it's the only use of the `$` operator which flex supports:

```
NAME (?x: foo | bar )$
```

Below are a few notes.

---

> In Flex, I can use the a trailing pattern in a name definition like this:
>
> ```
> NAME  foo$|bar
> ```

No, you can't. Or, better said, you can write that but it doesn't involve trailing context because:

> …a '$' which does not occur at the end of a rule loses its special properties and is treated as a normal character.

(From the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html); it's the last phrase in the point which says that you can't put trailing context operators inside parentheses.)

It is true (and slightly curious) that flex will reject:

```
NAME  (?x: foo$ | bar )
```

although it will accept:

```
NAME  (?x: foo$| bar )
```

I would go out on a limb and say that it is a bug. A <kbd>$</kbd> is recognized as a trailing context operator only if it is at the end of the pattern. However, the code which checks that simply checks to see if the next character is whitespace, because patterns terminate at the first whitespace character. (The pattern isn't parsed in the definition; it is parsed when it is actually included in some rule pattern.) The test does not check whether the <kbd>$</kbd> is within a `(?x:` block, so in

```
(?x: foo$ | bar )
```

the <kbd>$</kbd> is a trailing context operator, which is a syntax error (the operator must appear at the very end of the pattern), while in

```
(?x: foo$| bar )
```

the <kbd>$</kbd> is just an ordinary character, which is legal but perhaps unexpected.

---

Finally, a little note: the following is completely legal and the <kbd>$</kbd> will be treated as a trailing context operator, *provided that the definition is used at the very end of a pattern*:

```
NAME  bar|foo$
```

However, it probably doesn't mean what you think it means, either. The trailing context operator has lower precedence than the alternation operator, so as long as the expansion is at the end of a pattern, that is parsed as though it were written

```
NAME  (bar|foo)$
```

I would strongly recommend against using such a definition. (In fact, I generally discourage the use of definitions, partly because of all these quirks.) A definition which ends with a <kbd>$</kbd> is inserted into the referencing pattern without being surrounded with parentheses (so that the <kbd>$</kbd> could be treated as an operator). This leads to all sorts of unexpected behaviour. For example, if you write:

```
NAME  bar|foo$
```

and then use it:

```
x{NAME}y       /* Some action */
```

The end result will be as though you had written

```
xbar|foo"$"y   /* Some action */
```

(No parentheses, but the <kbd>$</kbd> is a regular character.)

On the other hand, if you use it like this:

```
x{NAME}        /* Some action */
```

That's as though you had written

```
xbar|foo$      /* Some action */
```

in which <kbd>$</kbd> is the trailing context operator, but because of the low precedence of that operator it ends up being equivalent to

```
(xbar|foo)$    /* Some action */
```

It's unlikely that any of those expansions were what you wanted, and even less likely that anyone reading your code will expect those results.

Comment: thank you this is very informative.  After I wrote the question, I realized myself what you wrote, that trailing context cannot be used in definitions, only in rules.  After reading your answer and more analysis of my problem, I now came to the conclusion that it is better for me to not use flex but write my own lexer, and connect it by standard interface to bison.

Comment: @Mark: You can use trailing context in a definition if you insist. A definition is just a macro, after all -- the only bit of intelligence flex applies is to (usually) surround the expansion with parentheses, and as the answer indicates, it often gets this wrong. So if you want to use trailing context in a definition, you need to use the definition only at the end of a rule, and you should insert parentheses yourself: definition: `FOO_OR_BAR_AT_EOL       (foo|bar)$`  use: `//.*{FOO_OR_BAR_AT_EOL}   {puts("comment ends with foo");}` will do pretty much what it looks like it will do....

Comment: ... but I wouldn't do that. I don't like using macros in C, either, and I only use definitions in Flex when there is an obvious benefit. To each their own, however. Despite a few rough edges, I personally believe that flex is a huge timesaver. YMMV. Good luck with your project.